# Have to tap twice on bottom part in ios safari browser

Tags: ios, safari, toolbar, footer

I have a button in bottom part of my website. On ios devices in safari browser, when i try to click it, it first opens footer section of browser and then i have to tap again to click the button. How can i click button in one tap?
Refer this GIF: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyciL.gif

Answer (score 0):

1. `height: 100vh` (this will set your content to have maximum possible height)
2. `overflow-y: scroll` (this will make that div/element scrollable and hence browser won't notice that you are scrolling when actually you are scrolling.)

Due to ios safari's default behaviour when you scroll on page it automatically hides header and footer of browser. Now if you have a button on bottom part of your website, you will have to tap twice to make it work. The first tap will trigger safari footer section (assuming you wanted to open footer section) and second tap will actually trigger click event on button.

One of main reason of this thing causing an issue is, whenever you scroll, safari notices that you have scrolled and you will keep scrolling. To show you maximum content on website it hides footer and addressbar. and that's why using `overflow-y: scroll` is mandatory.

**P.S.**
Because you are now scrolling within the div/element `window.addEventListener('scroll', function())` won't work anymore. To fix that, you can use `document.getElementById('your-div-id').addEventListener('scroll', function())`

Apart from this window.pageYoffset will always be 0. To get pageYOffset, you can use getBoundingRect property of the div on which `overflow-y:scroll` was added.

For example:`scrollPosition = document.getElementById('your-div-id').getBoundingClientRect().top`
This will give you height from top of the div till you have scrolled.

*Happy debugging*